# Height of a vertical LinearLayout

Tags: android, user-interface, layout

I am trying to come up with the following dialog:

[image]

Picture above shows what I have now. In the center, there's a vertically scrollable list of panes. Each Pane has an ImageView in the left, and three elements in the right: a TextView, another TextView and a Button.

Here's how the Pane is written:

```
<LinearLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:orientation="horizontal"
   <!-- .... -->                 >

   <ImageView
       android:scaleType="fitCenter"
       android:layout_width="0dp"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:layout_gravity="top"
       android:layout_weight="0.5"
       <!-- .... -->            >

   <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="0dp"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:layout_weight="1.0"
       <!-- .... -->            >

       <TextView
          android:gravity="top|start"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          <!-- .... -->                    />

       <TextView
          android:gravity="top|start"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          <!-- .... -->                    />

       <Button
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_gravity="bottom"
          <!-- .... -->                    />

   </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Now, this gives *almost* the desired effect. The problem I am struggling with is:

I would like the height of the single pane to be determined by the combined heights of the right three elements (the two TextViews and the Button). Unfortunately it is determined by the height of the left image (before scaling, i.e. before android applies the scaleType="fitCenter" - original images are much larger and get scaled down on most phones ).

So, as you ca see, each pane is too high and leaves unnecessary empty space below each button.

How could I correct this problem?

BTW, this is part of the free and open source Magic Cube app. You can download it here:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.distorted.magic&pli=1

and see the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it - one simply has to add the

```
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```

to the 'ImageView' section :)